# Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -11) PDF Print

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, odoo-12

When I print the report from Odoo it throws this error **Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -11).**
How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below link: https://gist.github.com/brunogaspar/bd89079245923c04be6b0f92af431c10

or you can use the below steps:

1. sudo apt-get remove --purge wkhtmltopdf
   **This command will remove the wkhtmltopdf**
   **Wkhtmltopdf is an open source simple and much effective command-line shell utility that enables user to convert any given HTML (Web Page) to PDF document or an image (jpg, png, etc).**
2. sudo apt-get remove --purge wkhtmltox
   **This command will remove the wkhtmltox**
   **The goal of this module is to provide high performance access to wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage from node.js.**
3. sudo apt-get install xvfb libfontconfig wkhtmltopdf
4. sudo apt-get -f install
5. sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer

**The ttf-mscorefonts-installer package allows for easy installation of the Microsoft True Type Core Fonts for the web. ... Wait a bit until the terminal tells you that it's finished downloading and installing the Microsoft TrueType core fonts.**

6. sudo fc-cache -f -v
   **fc-cache scans the font directories on the system and builds font information cache files for applications using fontconfig for their font handling. ... Each directory is scanned for font files readable by FreeType. A cache is created which contains properties of each font and the associated filename.**

Comment: I tried out the way you posted when i got the same error. Now i can download the report but it seems the content in pdf is not showing...it remains blank...could you help me in this case@himansu